# typescript keys from one interface and value as another type

Tags: typescript

I have a interface

```
interface User {
    firstName: string;
    secondName: string;
    age: number;
}
```

I wanted to create a new type with different value type

```
type CustomT = { regex: RegExp }
interface UserWithRegexp {
    firstName: CustomT;
    secondName: CustomT;
    age: CustomT;
}
```

How can i refractor the UserWithRegexp type by using the User interface

I am expecting to have something like this`type UserWithRegexp = { [key of User] : CustomT }`

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `Record<K, V>` type?

```js
type UserWithRegexp = Record<keyof User, CustomT>;
```

You should be able to use it like this.

```js
const userWithRegex: UserWithRegexp = {
    firstName: { regex: /.*/ },
    secondName: { regex: /.*/ },
    age: { regex: /.*/ },
};
```

Comment: You may want to note that [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0e905be42bd92d6679d43408deb818b09ff6c292/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1499-L1501) similarly to what the OP is asking for: `type UserWithRegexp = { [key in keyof User] : CustomT }`